# How to search by 13-digits NumberLong time field with pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, search, pymongo

In my mongodb I have a 13-digits field named 'time' (NumberLong), its content example: 1561463989574.
Now with my python3 and pymongo I want to select all the documents added after a certain date (for example: 25 june 2019).

In mongo shell this query works just fine:

```
db.mybase.find({"time":{$gte:new Date("25 Jun 2019").getTime()}} )
```

But in python I get no results with any queries. Example:

```
from_date = datetime(2019, 5, 24, 12, 59, 59, 125000)
cursor = collection.find({"time": {"$gte": from_date}})
for document in cursor: print(document)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Err, combined it:

```
datestr = "Wed Jun 25 00:00:00 2019 GMT"
timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(datestr, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z")) * 1000
cursor = collection.find({'time': {'$gte':timestamp}}).limit(10)
for document in cursor: print(document)
```